# Flutter Segment: Merge events for single user

Tags: flutter, segment, mixpanel

I am using Segment for analytics that is inter connected with
Mixpanel.

I've used this package for Flutter [segment](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics_flutter). I am adding the identify events when the user completes the signup process.

```
analytics?.identify(
      userId: session?.id.toString(),
      userTraits: UserTraits(
        custom: traits,
      ),
    );
```

before the signup I tracked some of the events that did not have `user_id` as value and these events keep `anonymousId` that is called before the `identify()` whereas in `Mixpanel` all these events should merge into single `user_id` that have same deviceId.

```
SegmentHelper.track(
        SegmentHelper.ACCOUNT_CREATED,
        properties: {
          'username': userNameController.text,
          'email': emailController.text,
        },
      );
```

[image: Please see the attached screenshots for that]

Kindly help me how can I merge the events before signup and after signup for same user.